# Chance of harvesting x herbs in Runescape

Tags: probability

I know that there existing a gaming Stack Exchange, but this question is purely a math problem. I'll try to avoid in-game terms as much as possible. It's been a while since I've tried to solve a problem like this, so apologies if it's obvious to you!

When you harvest an herb patch, you get a certain number of herbs, determined as follows:

The patch has 6 "lives". Each time you harvest an herb, it has a chance to "save a life" equal to

$$\text{saveLife} = \frac{n+1}{256} \cdot 1.1$$

where $n$ is your farming level and $n\in[1,99].$ Once the farming patch's lives hits zero, you stop harvesting.

The question is: What is the probability that you have harvested $x$ herbs given level $n$ farming?

My attempt involved taking the probability of each individual herb chance occurring. I used $n = 83$ to test it, leading to:

$$saveLife = \frac{83+1}{256}\cdot 1.1 \approx .361 $$

0-5 herbs: 0.0 because you have 6 lives

6 herbs: $(.361)^0\cdot (1-.361)^6 \cdot (6C0) \approx .068$ since you missed the save chance all 6 times.

7 herbs: $(.361)^1\cdot (1-.361)^7 \cdot (7C1) \approx .110$ since you hit the save chance once out of 7 times, and missed the other 6.

8 herbs: $(.361)^2\cdot (1-.361)^8 \cdot (8C2) \approx .101$

9 herbs: 0.0405

10 herbs: 0.021

11 herbs: 0.009

12 herbs: 0.004

13 herbs: 0.001

etc.

The issue I've run into is that the probabilities added together currently total around 43% and I know empirically that the you get under 13 herbs almost every time.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To harvest exactly $x$ herbs (where $x \ge 6$), the patch needs to:

1. save a life $x-6$ times during the first $x-1$ attempts
2. fail to save a life $5$ times during the first $x-1$ attempts
3. fail to save a life on the $x$-th attempt.

If the patch saves a life on the $x$-th attempt, you'd have an $(x+1)$-th attempt, and thus, get more than $x$ herbs.

So, the probability of harvesting exactly $x$ herbs is $$P_x = \dbinom{x-1}{x-6}p^{x-6}(1-p)^6$$ where $p$ is the probability of the patch saving a life. You should be able to check that $\displaystyle\sum_{x = 6}^{\infty}P_x = 1$.